# How to prevent phone to install bloatware automatically

Tags: applications, antivirus, bloatware, firewall

I have a `THL T9 Plus`. I just wonder, why are applications installed automatically in background. I already installed `NoRoot Firewall` and `Avira Antivirus`. These are in most cases "HotKnotBean" and "Coordinator" named applications. I get notification by Avira, when these are installed and I can remove these too, but unable to protect phone from installation of these.

Comment: Have you tried turn off 'install app from unknown sources' in the security settings?

Comment: @Beveloper : Yes, but somehow applications are installed silently in the background.

Comment: there seem to be an app on your phone that has the permission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES used for installing apps, so as long has that app is installed or is given that permission it will continue. Use apps like Startup Manager or Task Killer to see if you could find out which app is doing the downloads. Or use permissions management tool on lolipop and above to check apps permissions

Answer (score 1):

Looks like malware in your phone is pre-installed by manufacturer.

It's better to install another ROM.
You may check [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2F4pda.ru%2Fforum%2Findex.php%3Fact%3Dsearch%26query%3D%25EF%25F0%25EE%25F8%25E8%25E2%25EA%25E0%26username%3D%26forums%255B%255D%3D650%26topics%3D792265%26source%3Dpst%26sort%3Ddd%26result%3Dposts) which one owners of your device recommend.